# PHP SDK - How to get example.php to work?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I downloaded the PHP SDK from Github (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) on my server, but cannot get example.php to work:

1. When I open example.php in Safari I get - you are not connected
2. I click the login link
3. I enter user and pass to Facebook
4. The browser redirects back to my example.php - there's "state"
   and "code" params in the URL
5. example.php still shows "you are not connected" (which is the
   essence of my problem)
6. If I add: `print $facebook->getAccessToken();` - it prints an Access
   Token (!!!)

So my question is - what's example.php's problem? 
If I have an access token from Facebook, why `$facebook->getUser()` returns nothing?

How to the get example.php working, so I can continue developing my own logic onwards?

---

PS: at the same time the PHP code example here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ works just fine, so it looks I have a problem with php-sdk from Github ... is the Github library stable or rather work in progress, which cannot be used for production?

Comment: is it possible to show the contents of example.php?  I have used FB API, but not their SDK's

Comment: here you go: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php , on a side not the plain php example from FB's website works for me

Comment: please remove the cookie with fbs_ or fbsr_ prefix and try it again. If it still gives you error then let us know it is fbs_(Oauth) or fbsr_(Oauth 2.0).

Comment: I had one cookie called : fb_312545812129094_state, deleted all cookies I had, but the problem still persist. Tried with couple more browsers just in case, but nothing

Comment: Oh may be I got it. For your app oauth 1.x is enabled instead of Oauth 2.0. Just go to your app setting page. click on edit settings and then go to Advance tab. and check whether **Encrypted Access Token:** is enabled or not. It should be enabled. and delete that fb_ cookie before rerun.

Comment: ok got it ... without any changes it started to work - it looks like when you download the php-sdk and create an app @ Facebook it looks like for few hours you get strange results ... I remember they have a little label saying I could expect that ... though they could've somehow make it more apparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it ... several hours after you create a Facebook app it looks you get rather strange results from the API. It seems that example.php works now without any changes - I really believe it was the API server's fault, cz the code definitely works now.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of PHP SDK you downloaded. PHP SDK version 2.0 has this issue.

`$facebook->getUser()` returns nothing.

This is solved in PHP SDK 3.0. Download version 3 and try with that.

Comment: I got 3.1.1 - 6 hours ago and struggling with this ever since

Comment: I checked with your code and its working fine for me.   can you try with this in your example.php.                               $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_ID,
  'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));

Answer (score 0):

The example script does not add the baseurl params while initialising the facebook object. I also spent hours trying to debug the same. The example with js worked. There after once i added the baseurl it worked.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '406058216186755',
  'secret' => 'adsaqer4sdfsdgfgfg21341324324',
  'baseurl' => 'http://ironhide.maanas.co/oauth/facebook.php'
));
```

Answer (score -1):

are you sure you used: **echo** $facebook->getUser() ?

I recommend you: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Use PHP SDK v3, the v2 is bugged !

Good luck

Comment: Here's the source from github, this should answer your question: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php